# Next-Auth works on local but not on vercel - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: vercel, next-auth, next.js13

### Project Info

Next.js 13.4 using app router > Next auth 4.22.1 > Vercel deployment.
NEXTAUTH_URL and NERXTAUTH_SECRET are set as env variables on Vercel.

### The Problem

When I have my project running on localhost, everything seems to work fine. However when I push to Vercel, 100% of my login attempts bring me to an error page that just says "Error" with the url under it. Doesnt matter if password and username is correct or wrong, i get the same plain error page.

### test website Link

Here is my test deploy. The login button is actually the colored (green) button in the middle of the hero section that says "sign in". (was the easiest place to place it for testing).

https://jinmatestapi.vercel.app/

### Vercel Logs

I found this error on vercel logs but cant figure out how to use it to fix my issue.  (on further investigation it seems like it's coming from the api/login page by trying to json pare the request. Credentials are sent just fine, but something is getting lost in transit on vercel. not sure how to fix this)

```
    - error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6571:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6545:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1211:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

## The Code

### Here is my test api/[...nextauth] route

```
    import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "test" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials && credentials.username,
            password: credentials && credentials.password,
          }),
        });


        const user = await res.json();

        if (user) {
          return user;
        }
          return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

### **Here is my test api/login route**

```
    // This is where we want to get the user from the database and compare the password

import { signJwtAccessToken } from 'jinma/auth/jwt';


export async function POST(request) {
  const body = await request.json();

  const user = {
    id: 1,
    username: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }


if (user && (body.password === user.password) ) {
  const { password, ...userWithoutPass } = user;
  const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken(userWithoutPass);
  const result = {
    ...userWithoutPass,
    accessToken,
  };
  console.log("RESULT", result);
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(result));
} 
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(null));
}
```

### Also here is the JWT code for full context just in case.

```
    import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const DEFAULT_SIGN_OPTION = {
  expiresIn: "30d",
};

function signJwtAccessToken(payload, options = DEFAULT_SIGN_OPTION) {
  const secret_key = 'testkeykjdlkfajsdlkfjlasdkfjasldkflkasdjfas';
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret_key, options);
  return token;
}

function verifyJwt(token) {
  try {
    const secret_key = 'testkeykjdlkfajsdlkfjlasdkfjasldkflkasdjfas';
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret_key);
    return decoded;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}

export { signJwtAccessToken, verifyJwt };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to signin with Next-auth in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314765/unable-to-signin-with-next-auth-in-production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer was given in https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7887#discussioncomment-6646858 by [jamesallchin-rb](https://github.com/jamesallchin-rb). Their issue was related to using `fetch` and was possibly related to having different Node versions between their localhost and Vercel. They resolved their issue by switching to use `axios`.

Ex. From this:

> ```js
> const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/login`, {
>   method: "POST",
>   headers: {
>     "Content-Type": "application/json",
>   },
>   body: JSON.stringify({
>     username: credentials && credentials.username,
>     password: credentials && credentials.password,
>   }),
> });
> ```

To this:

> ```js
> const res = await axios({
>   method: 'POST',
>   url: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/login`,
>   data: credentials,
>   headers: {
>     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>   },
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When running locally instead of `npm run dev` run `vercel dev`. If the former works and the latter doesn't, something within your vercel.json is most likely misconfigured. In my case I completely removed it (the configuration i had in there wasn't needed)  and it worked.