# Unable to signin with Next-auth in production

Tags: next.js, oauth, vercel, next-auth

I've deployed my next.js application in vercel and I use Next-auth for authentication. In my app user can signin with google OAuth and it works perfectly locally but in production the user is not able to signin

When i check the logs of my deployment this is what i see
[image]

Here the cache says `MISS`
I found this [issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2408) in github and tried to override the header both in `next.config.js` and in the auth handler but the bug is still not fixed.

what am i missing out?
here is the link to my project repository: https://github.com/alphawhiskey03/bmi-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in development we put next auth url in the .env file

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

make sure to put this in production to your new domain

```
NEXTAUTH_URL= your new domain here
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the log of Google auth page. It is possible that you pass redirect URL or main URL wrong.

Please check the Redirect URL in your `Google console` and what you pass in `env` of your app in Vercel. It is possible that your Redirect URL is `localhost` and NOT the `Vercel` URL!

Comment: Thanks. i double checked the points that you had mentioned as well and finally i found out that i was specifying the wrong NEXTAUTH_URL in production