# Next Auth signIn function works as expected in development, fail in production on Vercel

Tags: vercel, next.js13, next-auth

UPDATE:

Another weird behaviour identified:

- When I try to log in on chrome (laptop, macOS), the log in fails with a 405 and I get redirected to /login#

[image]

- When I try to log in from safari (either macOS or iOS), the log in fails with a 304 and I get redirected to next-auth's standard error page: /api/auth/error

[image]

INITIAL:

I am using next-auth to manage auth in my Next.js 13 app.

The following code deals with the email-and-password sign in method, and works as expected in development:

```js
<button
  type="submit"
  disabled={!isFormValid()}
  className={`flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-amber-500 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:amber-indigo-600 ${isFormValid()? 'hover:bg-amber-700' : ''
}`}              
  onClick={() => signIn('credentials', {email, password, redirect: true, callbackUrl: '/dashboard'})}
>
  Sign In
</button>
```

But fails in production on Vercel:

[image]

[image]

My NEXTAUTH_URL is properly set up.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions provided here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568550/next-auth-works-on-local-but-not-on-vercel-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json

Comment: yes. doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure to set `NEXTAUTH_URL` for prod

```
NEXTAUTH_URL="PLACE_DOMAIN_URL_HERE"
```

Comment: My NEXTAUTH_URL is properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure accessibility on the client-side, it's advisable to use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_*` to this variable, making it `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_URL`.